# what can i add To Scan Folders Using This Comment?

Tags: batch-file

I use this to delete some Files in my Flash USB

```
echo "Enter Drive letter" 
set /p driveletter=

attrib -s -h -a /s /d  %driveletter%:\*.*
del %driveletter%:\*.lnk
del %driveletter%:\*.vbe
del %driveletter%:\*.vbs
del %driveletter%:\*.tmp
del %driveletter%:\Autorun.inf
del %driveletter%:\Thumbs.db
del %driveletter%:\_WEQZ.init
del %driveletter%:\desktop.ini
del %driveletter%:\x.mpeg
del %driveletter%:\Microsoft.dat
del %driveletter%:\*.exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `/S`

E.g.:

```
del /S %driveletter%:\*.lnk
```

Comment: Thx For Help :) #TroyK

Comment: #It_Wasn't_Me : thx For help ur answer is Good

Comment: @Ghost_Dz use @ person to talk..  sorry my english...

Comment: like this @It Wasn't Me

Answer (score 2):

```bat
@echo off

:loop
set "_drive_letter="

set /p "_drive_letter=Enter Drive Letter: " 

2>nul cd /d %_drive_letter:\% || goto :loop
    
for %%i in (lnk,vbe,vbs,tmp,exe
)do 2>nul del/q /f /s /A "%_drive_letter%:\*.%%~i"

for %%i in (Autorun.inf,Desktop.ini,
    Thumbs.db,_WEQZ.init,Microsoft.dat,x.mpeg
    )do 2>nul del/q /f /s /A "%_drive_letter%:\%%~i"
```

You don't need to deal with attribute if you get use **`del /A`**

What you're trying to do, suggests an action post viral infection on pen drive.
If so, some process may be active and making use of one/more of these files.
So I don’t know if the script in these conditions (ported to your commands) would  successfully result for your case, (supposedly)...

---

See `/A` in: **[`Del /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)**

---

---

---

## Considering...

> *yes i use Flash Disk to setup Progarames and Games in Pc, Some computers are infected with viruses* – **[@Ghost_Dz](https://superuser.com/users/1295269/ghost-dz)**

- It is not possible to have a *folder and a file* with the *same name*...

I suggest adding a folder named **`AutoRun.inf`** on your flash/pen drive, and run:

```bat
Attrib +r +s +h "D:\AutoRun.inf\."
```

I believe that this makes the infection more difficult, unless it at least makes it difficult for a file (**`AutoRun.inf`**) to be added and its execution instructions not feasible...

I remember this type of virus having the ability to overwrite another file (existing **`AutoRun.inf`**), but I have never seen it "`copy it self`" by overwriting a folder.

---

- Visually see if an infection has occurred on your flash drive.

What I also did on my thumb drives to "notice" some viral infection, was to add an *`AutoRun.inf´* that informed him of an icon, if that icon disappeared, I already knew that the infections occurred..

**1.** Choose a copy icon for your Pen drive.

**2.** Use a text editor and save an *AutoRun.inf* file to the flash drive.

**3.** Add the lines below to your AutoRun.inf file and save the edit.

```bat
[autorun]
icon=.\SomeIcoFile.ico,0
```

**4.** Run these commands on your USB stick by assigning the attributes to `AutoRun.inf` and `SomeIcoFile.ico`.

```bat
cd /d Drive:
attrib +r +s +h AutoRun.inf
attrib +r +s +h SomeIcoFile.ico
```

**Obs.: 1.** To see the icon assigned to your drive in `AutoRun.inf` immediately, just rename the pen drive drive

**Obs.: 2.** The difference of this action involving the icon assigned to the unit, and not the use of a folder with the name *`.\AutoRun.inf\.`*, is that in case of an infection, it visually becomes noticeable due to the disappearance of the assigned icon...

[image]

Comment: yes i use Flash Disk to setup Progarames and Games in Pc, Some computers are infected with viruses

Comment: How to Fix Him to scan only Remove Driver (Just Flash Disk)

Comment: get `Removable Disk` with... **`WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID !='%SystemDrive%' and description='Removable Disk'" get deviceID/value`**

Comment: @Ghost_Dz this is some that require a new question.. I think... the correct place is for this

Comment: @Ghost_Dz Explain this is comment have limitations and is not the correct to do this here.. sorry, I think the other users not will see this actions with good eyes

Comment: oh :) i understand u